# How to find ratio to maintain different sizes in dimens folder

Tags: android, android-layout

I have gone through sites like 
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html
and few other sites. Yet one thing is not clear to me regarding how to find out the ratio to place values in different dimens folders. I have placed different `dimens` folders like `values-sw300dp`,`values-sw-320dp` and so on in my project.So lets consider I have a dimen value in basic dimen file

```
<dimen name="tab_gray_color_image_width_height">50dp</dimen>
```

So when I need to place the same value in vales-sw-600dp folder , do I need to multiply it or add it by some x value to maintain the ratio ? Or is there some co relation. When I log the values what I have found out is that the device multiplies the mdpi value with its screen density and considers it like

```
2*mdpi value
1.5*mdpi value
```

So for above value `50` it will calculate `1.5 * 50` or `2* 50` according to screen density.
  and so on. So if the device itself is calculating the value , what is the need of of many different dimens file.? And is there some ratio or formulae which needs to be applied to place different values in different dimens folder ?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you should say what you're actually trying to do (what layout you are trying to accomplish).

Comment: @ianhanniballake Actually I was trying to achieve a layout where I used collapsible toolbar. I achieved what I wanted to, but for every different kind of device(density + size) I had to test different values in the dimens folder and it is time consuming, hence trying to find out if there is a generalized formulae.

Comment: So you want a view in a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` that fills the width of the screen but always has the same aspect ratio no matter the device?

Comment: @ianhanniballake both height and width. I have an image which decreases its size when the user scrolls up, and I need to give its appbarLayout a fixed size due to layout complicities,which I take from dimens values as I mentioned in question, but it messes up when I use devices of different sizes more than densities.The image manages itself programmatically. I achieved the size problem by trail and error in different dimens file. I cannot display the whole layout due to privacy reasons.So basically is there some generalised formula to calculate values in different dimens file ?

Comment: Why can't you just add [android:adjustViewBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) to your `ImageView`? That'll adjust the `ImageView` automatically to fit the image. A screenshot of what you are trying to do would be helpful here.

Comment: Ok let me give it a try.

Comment: I had used this property earlier , and it did not work at that time as expected. Frankly speaking its working as of now, what I need, with the adjustments. The issue I faced here was not as much as about image, but more about adjusting dimens file for different sizes,at more than one place,not inclusive to image.Btw thank you for the efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Try this DPI Calculators

1)http://jennift.com/dpical.html

2) http://angrytools.com/android/pixelcalc/

Comment: px = dp * (dpi / 160) this the only formula provided in [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do that at all. You should instead use [android:adjustViewBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds) on your `ImageView` to automatically adjust the size of the `ImageView` based on the size of the image being displayed.